# Is there a unique identifier for a user across different Google APIs?

Tags: youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, uniqueidentifier, google-oauth

I am using google's oauth2 to allow users to register/login into my site (php library). The first time a user attempts to login I get the user's email address and google+ id which are provided by the Google OAuth2 API (with the user's permission).

In a different part of the site I need some information from the user's youtube channel. I am using the incremental authorization to get the extra permissions as it is recommended (and described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth ).

The problem is that I don't have a unique identifier for the user between the calls, in order to keep track of him/her in my side of the application. A user, for example might have multiple youtube channels and each one can be associated with a different google+ account/id and a different email address, which most of the time is not a real address but a provided email with the format 'username-XXXX@plus.google.com'.

I was wondering if google's apis can return a unique identifier for the 'parent' account of a user across different apis.

Thanks in advance.